# Count the total number of times the ID appears

Tags: dataframe, count

I have a dataframe with ID and year. I want to add a column of count which counts the total number of times the ID appears and assigns the number in front of each observation.
The dataframe after result should look like this.

```py
>ID  year  count
>1   2012  3
>1   2013  3
>1   2014  3
>2   2012  3
>2   2013  3
>2   2014  3
>3   2012  1
>4   2012  2
>4   2013  2
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO. It's not clear what you're asking, can you provide more of an example?

Comment: My bad for the sample data looking like that.

Comment: ID year count 1 2012 3....indicates first row...the count value in each row indicates the total number of times ID appears. How do I generate the column count which counts the total number of times ID is repeated in the data

Comment: what python code should i write for this. Groupby gives the aggregate count by unique ID and not individual rows